# How to shorten a directory path pattern

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line

I have a set of about 10.000 directories that have the following structure

```
./AAA/AAA/somedirs/file.txt
..
./BCDE/BCDE/somedirs/file.txt
..
./FGMAB/FGMAB/somedirs/file.txt
..
etc
```

I want to reduce the recurring directory path pattern of two consecutive directories with the same name:

```
./X/X/etc/
```

to a single directory with that name:

```
./X/etc/
```

I thought of finding all substructures after such a X/X pattern and move them to X/  with a command like:

```
for /r /d %x in (*/%y/%y/*) do move "%x" ".."
```

This does run, but it doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Anyone an idea if and how this could be done?

Comment: If you want to shorten a relative path that seems too long, you'll have to go to that path to make it current (i.e.: "."). Use `PUSHD`, `CD`, and `POPD` to go back and forth to a specific path in order to temporarily use a shorter relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the duplicate names are all at the top of the tree structure as shown, something like this should work:

```
md dummy\x
for /D %x in (*) do if exist %x\%x cmd /c "move %x dummy\x\%x & move dummy\x\%x\%x %x & rd dummy\x\%x"
```

Test it first!  (And remember the percentage signs need to be doubled up when the command is in a batch file.)

Comment: Thanks, this works! For anyone trying to do the same trick just remember that you need to add additional quotes around directories and file occurences if they contain spaces, e.g. `"%x\%x"` instead of `%x\%x`. The following code does the same trick as above, but in just one line without dummy dir necessary: `for /D %x in (*) do if exist %x\%x cmd /c "for /D
%y in ("%x\%x\*") do move "%y" "%x"" & rd "%x/%x"`

Comment: Fair enough.  Note, however, that your approach won't work if there are any files at the second level, i.e., `.\aaa\aaa\file.txt`, or if there are any directory names that repeat three times, i.e., `.\aaa\aaa\aaa\file.txt`.  Whether these are potential problems depends on the scenario.